Why is the induced Matrix (1,2) norm the maximum 2-norm of any column?
I have read this on the wikipedia page for Matrix Norms. But I'm having trouble proving it. Unfortunately there is no citation in wiki, and (probably because it isn't a very searchable phrase), I can't find anything on the (1,2) norm elsewhere on the internet.
I was able to show one direction, namely that
$$\sup_{||x||_1=1}||Ax||_2=\sup_{||x||_1=1}||\sum_i A_ix_i||_2 \geq \max_i ||A_i||_2,$$
where $A_i$ is the i-th column of $A$, and $x_i$ is a scalar. I did so by letting $x=e_i,$ where $i$ is the index of the column with the largest 2-norm, and then using the triangle inequality.
My attempt so far at showing that $$\sup_{||x||_1=1}||Ax||_2 \leq \max_i ||A_i||_2$$
has only resulted in being able to upper bound the quantity of interest by $n \max_i ||A_i||_2$, which I can get to simply with the triangle inequality, or $\sqrt{n} \max_i||A_i||_2,$ which I got to with Jensen's inequality.
Any ideas on how to show this other direction?
as a secondary question, is there a book that covers these lesser-known induced (p,q) norms well? I also have a question about the (1,inf) norm, and would like to do my own research on that if possible.
-Paul

By subadditivity of norm, we have $\|\sum_i x_iA_i\|_2\le \sum_i |x_i|\|A_i\|_2 \le \max_{i}\|A_i\|_2$. The last "$\leq$" is due to the fact that $\|x\|_1 = 1$.
This note seems a good reference (but I'm not sure it covers all your need).

that was exactly my attempt using the triangle inequality. But isn't the last step missing a factor of n?

no missing $n$. $|x_1|+\dots+|x_n| = 1$, we assign $x_i = 1$ to the largest column 2-norm of $A$ and all other $x_j$ to be zero.

ahh, you're right. The first equation seems sufficient for me. It seems like if we just replace A_i with the max column, we don't need to fix any particular value of x though, because we then have $A_{max}\sum |x_i| = A_{max}$.. isn't that true for any x?
